# Argument to printf to be used as an argument to format specifier

Tags: c, string-formatting

Suppose I have the following function:

```
void fprint(float f, int ds) {
    printf("%.%df\n", ds, f);
}
```

I want the caller to specify the float to print, as well as the number of digits after the decimal point. (indicated by the `.%d` specifier)

However, when compiling this I get 2 warnings:

```
./sprint.h: In function ‘fprint’:
./sprint.h:19:14: warning: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Wformat=]
     printf("%.%df\n", ds, f);
          ^
```

and

```
./sprint.h:19:12: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     printf("%.%df\n", ds, f);
            ^~~~~~~~~
```

And when calling it: `fprint(3.1422223f, 3);`, it produces the output: `%df`.
I also tried swapping the order of the arguments in the function declaration, but it produces the same warnings.

My question is: how can I inject a format specifier (such as `%d` in this case) into an existing format specifier?

Comment: try using sprintf to first create the string to use in the printf

Comment: See the answer that Ry- posted. The correct syntax for doing this is `%.*f` not `%.%df`. This is described in the documentation for `printf` format specifiers.

Comment: Once you figured out the "how", which might be an interesting learning experience, note that allowing the user to control the format string is a gaping security hole (as this can be used to peek the stack, and even write things into it, compromising your application, and possibly -- through other exploits -- the system you are running it on). Allowing the user to control *parts* of the format string is only marginally better, as you will (hopefully) spend lots of time figuring out how to sanitize the user input. *Is it really worth it?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an asterisk with `printf` to specify that a width or precision is given by an argument – no need to create a dynamic format string.

```
printf("%.*f", ds, f);
```

man-pages’s printf(3):

> #### Precision
>
> An optional precision, in the form of a period (`.`)  followed by an optional decimal digit string.  **Instead of a decimal digit string one may write `*`** or `*m$` (for some decimal integer m) **to specify that the precision is given in the next argument**, or in the m-th argument, respectively, **which must be of type int.**  If the precision is given as just `.`, the precision is taken to be zero.  A negative precision is taken as if the precision were omitted. This gives the minimum number of digits to appear for `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, and `X` conversions, the number of digits to appear after the radix character for `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, and `F` conversions, the maximum number of significant digits for `g` and `G` conversions, or the maximum number of characters to be printed from a string for `s` and `S` conversions.

Comment: Note that the man page discusses `m$`, which is an extension to the Standard C library.

Answer (score 0):

The `printf()` format string does not need to be a constant text string. It can also be a character string variable or a character array that contains a format specifier.

```
char fmt[256];
int  lVal = 5;

strcpy (fmt, "this %d\n");
printf (fmt, lVal);
```

By using a character string for the format specifier, you can do any modifications you want so long as the argument list supplied to the `printf()` function agrees with the format string.

You can also do the fly changes by concatenating pieces of a format specifier to build a complete format string or you can build a format specifier string using a function such as `sprintf()`.

Comment: I know, though I was specifically wondering if it was possible to use a conversion specifier inside one already in the format string.